# Need to Zero Angular Momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, simulations, molecular-dynamics

I'm writing a molecular dynamics simulation and need to zero the angular momentum of a collection of particles.  For each particle I know the location, mass and velocity.  My rotational physics is a bit lacking so I'm not quite sure where to start.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "zero the angular momentum"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, the angular momentum of the collection of particles around the center of mass is equal to zero

Comment: In theory, there are an infinite number of configurations where this is satisfied. What other characteristics must the system have?

Comment: @MD Simulation: why? All the particles have the same angular velocity?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to find a rotating frame of reference such that the angular momentum is zero in it (there should be just one such frame). Then you want to know the velocities in this frame of reference.